# В массиве из 20 целых чисел найти наибольший элемент и поменять его местами с первым элементом. Питон выдает ошибку, выход за массив, как исправить?

Tags: python

```
a = [int(input()) for i in range(20)]
Max = 0
for i in range(20+1):
    if a[i] > Max:
        Max = a[i]
    a[1] = Max
print(a)
```

Comment: Нумерация элементов списка начинается с `0`, поэтому не нужно к `20` прибавлять `1` в `range`. И индекс первого элемента `0` будет, а не `1`. И вы не поменяли местами элементы, а только присвоили одному значение другого.

Answer (score 3):

Можно вот так вот решить:

```
a = [int(input()) for _ in range(20)]
a_i_m = a.index(max(a))
a[0], a[a_i_m] = a[a_i_m], a[0]
print(a)
```